# Spring boot not picking value from environment variable in windows

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, application.properties

I have declared `db url`, `db user` and `db password` in `application.properties` like this

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DB_PASS}
```

This works in Ubuntu 16.04 but it is not working in windows 7, and the web application is not starting and in logs, it is showing,

> Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerDriver claims not to
>   accept jdbcurl, ${SPRING_DB_URL}

I tried setting the environment variable with key like this, 
`spring_datasource_url` but that too is not working.

the app is build as `war` file

Why this works in Ubuntu but not in Windows 7?

Comment: How do you run your app ? Maven, ide or jar ?

Comment: why don't you use `SPRING_DB_URL` as key?

Comment: @MartinChoraine, it is a war file and deployed using tomcat manager

Comment: @Deadpool that is what i initialy tried

Answer (score 1):

From [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) So use the key in upper case letters with combination of underscore if needed

> If you use environment variables rather than system properties, most operating systems disallow period-separated key names, but you can use underscores instead (for example, `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME` instead of `spring.config.name`).

Comment: so you are saying that I should use `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`

Comment: Yes i believe, give a chance @Sony

Comment: Little late here I did all the above then restarted my IDE (Intellij) worked great